# How to split string into an alphabetic string and a numeric string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-split

I need to use `preg_split()` function to split string into alpha and numeric.

Ex: `ABC10000` into, `ABC` and `10000`

`GSQ39800` into `GSQ` and `39800`

`WERTYI67888` into `WERTYI` and `67888`

Alpha characters will be the first characters(any number of) of the string always and then the numeric(any number of).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code or regex writing service. What have you tried so far to figure this out yourself?

Comment: @KenWhite I tried `/([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)/` with preg_match unfortunately didn't work with preg_split.  What do you think it is for then ?

Comment: I think it's for solving problems that people have once they've made an effort and couldn't do it. It's not a free coding service where you post your requirements and language of choice and someone does your work for you. If you *tried this*, it should be in your question to show the effort, and you should explain why it didn't satisfy your needs. If it's not in your post, it doesn't exist as far as we know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tiny task.  Use `\K` with matching on an capital letters in a character class using a one or more quantifier:

Code:

```
$in='WERTYI67888';
var_export(preg_split('/[A-Z]+\K/',$in));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'WERTYI',
  1 => '67888',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

using `preg_match`

```
$keywords = "ABC10000";
preg_match("#([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)#", $keywords, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

output

```
Array
(
    [0] => ABC10000
    [1] => ABC
    [2] => 10000
)
```

Comment: OP doesn't need the fullstring match, that is why `preg_split()` is requested

Comment: he ask regex, just for alternative